# Show / hide based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My current markup looks like this:

```
<div class="box" ng-click="showMe($event)">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
</div>
```

and in my controller:

```
$scope.showMe = function(event) {
  $(event.target).find('p').toggle();
};
```

Is there a way firstly to get rid of the jQuery dependency as I'm using Angular, and secondly - how can I make it so I show only a specific set of rows - so I have a condition which can show only 5 p tags for example?

Comment: check the `ng-show`, `ng-hide` in angular this will easy to use rather than using jquery, and do a bit of study regarding angular directives :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-show` on a bounding div to toggle visibility. To change the number of p tags, use the `ng-repeat` directive to control how many tags are shown from the controller.

```
<div class="box" ng-click="showMe()">
  <div ng-show="isVisible">
    <p ng-repeat="n in tags">
      {{n}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the controller, create the tags dynamically, and add the click handler for visibility toggling:

```
var numTags = 5;
var i = 0;
$scope.tags = [];

while (i < numTags){
  $scope.tags.push(i+1);
  i++;
}

$scope.showMe=function(){
  $scope.isVisible=!$scope.isVisible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your view markup

```
<div class="box" ng-click="showMe()">
   <div ng-show="isVisible">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is your controller function

```
$scope.showMe=function(){
  $scope.isVisible=!$scope.isVisible;
}
```